# .NET Mvc : The end-of-file marker was not found after downloading PDF

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, itext, pdf-reader

I'm 
1.Reading PDF file field Ids,

2.Storing in Dictionary as  Pair,

3.Iterating all the fields and Setting Values.For Step 2&3 Code is added Below,

```
 var pdfContents = PDFHelper.GeneratePDF(pdfPath, formFieldMap);

 public static byte[] GeneratePDF(string pdfPath, Dictionary<string, string> formFieldMap)
        {
            var output = new MemoryStream();
            var reader = new PdfReader(pdfPath);
            var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, output);
            var formFields = stamper.AcroFields;
            foreach (var fieldName in formFieldMap.Keys)
            {
                if (formFieldMap[fieldName] != null)
                {
                    formFields.SetField(fieldName, formFieldMap[fieldName]);
                }
            }
            stamper.FormFlattening = true;
            stamper.Writer.CloseStream = false;
            stamper.Close();
            reader.Close();
 return output.ToArray();
        }
```

4.Downloading in Local System using below code,

```
 PDFHelper.ReturnPDF(pdfContents, "CMS-1500.pdf");


 public static void ReturnPDF(byte[] contents, string attachmentFilename)
        {
            var response = HttpContext.Current.Response;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(attachmentFilename))
                response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + attachmentFilename);

            response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            response.BinaryWrite(contents);
            response.End();
        }
```

5.I can able to download file,But if i try to open I'm getting "Failed to open",Then I tried to repair PDF file using `https://www.pdf-online.com/osa/repair.aspx`, I got an error message as following,

```
Open file.
0x80410108 - E - The end-of-file marker was not found.
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x8041010A - E - The 'startxref' keyword or the xref position was not found.
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x80410108 - E - The end-of-file marker was not found.
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
Recover XREF table.
0x80410306 - E - The "Length" key of the stream object is wrong.
    - Object No.: 648
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x80410307 - E - The "endstream" keyword is missing.
    - Object No.: 648
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x8041010E - E - The file trailer dictionary is missing or invalid.
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
Analyze Objects.
0x80410306 - E - The "Length" key of the stream object is wrong.
    - Object No.: 648
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x80410307 - E - The "endstream" keyword is missing.
    - Object No.: 648
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x80410306 - E - The "Length" key of the stream object is wrong.
    - Object No.: 648
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x80410307 - E - The "endstream" keyword is missing.
    - Object No.: 648
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
Analyze Outlines.
Analyze Pages.
0x80410113 - E - The file is corrupt and cannot be repaired. Some of the contents can possibly be recovered.
    - Page No.: 2
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
Recover Pages.
Save output file.
0x80410515 - E - The form xobject Xi0 has an empty or unreadable content stream.
    - Page No.: 1
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x80410515 - E - The form xobject Xi1 has an empty or unreadable content stream.
    - Page No.: 1
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x80410515 - E - The form xobject Xi2 has an empty or unreadable content stream.
    - Page No.: 1
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x80410515 - E - The form xobject Xi3 has an empty or unreadable content stream.
    - Page No.: 1
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x80410515 - E - The form xobject Xi4 has an empty or unreadable content stream.
    - Page No.: 1
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x80410515 - E - The form xobject Xi5 has an empty or unreadable content stream.
    - Page No.: 1
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x80410515 - E - The form xobject Xi6 has an empty or unreadable content stream.
    - Page No.: 1
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x80410515 - E - The form xobject Xi7 has an empty or unreadable content stream.
    - Page No.: 1
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x80410515 - E - The form xobject Xi8 has an empty or unreadable content stream.
    - Page No.: 1
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x80410515 - E - The form xobject Xi9 has an empty or unreadable content stream.
    - Page No.: 1
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x80410515 - E - The form xobject Xi10 has an empty or unreadable content stream.
    - Page No.: 1
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x80410515 - E - The form xobject Xi11 has an empty or unreadable content stream.
    - Page No.: 1
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x80410515 - E - The form xobject Xi12 has an empty or unreadable content stream.
    - Page No.: 1
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x80410515 - E - The form xobject Xi13 has an empty or unreadable content stream.
    - Page No.: 1
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x80410515 - E - The form xobject Xi15 has an empty or unreadable content stream.
    - Page No.: 1
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x80410515 - E - The form xobject Xi16 has an empty or unreadable content stream.
    - Page No.: 1
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x80410515 - E - The form xobject Xi17 has an empty or unreadable content stream.
    - Page No.: 1
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x80410515 - E - The form xobject Xi18 has an empty or unreadable content stream.
    - Page No.: 1
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x80410515 - E - The form xobject Xi19 has an empty or unreadable content stream.
    - Page No.: 1
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x80410515 - E - The form xobject Xi20 has an empty or unreadable content stream.
    - Page No.: 1
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x80410515 - E - The form xobject Xi21 has an empty or unreadable content stream.
    - Page No.: 1
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x80410515 - E - The form xobject Xi22 has an empty or unreadable content stream.
    - Page No.: 1
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x80410515 - E - The form xobject Xi23 has an empty or unreadable content stream.
    - Page No.: 1
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x80410515 - E - The form xobject Xi24 has an empty or unreadable content stream.
    - Page No.: 1
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x80410515 - E - The form xobject Xi25 has an empty or unreadable content stream.
    - Page No.: 1
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x80410515 - E - The form xobject Xi26 has an empty or unreadable content stream.
    - Page No.: 1
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x80410515 - E - The form xobject Xi27 has an empty or unreadable content stream.
    - Page No.: 1
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x80410515 - E - The form xobject Xi28 has an empty or unreadable content stream.
    - Page No.: 1
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x80410515 - E - The form xobject Xi29 has an empty or unreadable content stream.
    - Page No.: 1
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x80410515 - E - The form xobject Xi30 has an empty or unreadable content stream.
    - Page No.: 1
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x80410515 - E - The form xobject Xi31 has an empty or unreadable content stream.
    - Page No.: 1
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x80410515 - E - The form xobject Xi32 has an empty or unreadable content stream.
    - Page No.: 1
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x80410515 - E - The form xobject Xi33 has an empty or unreadable content stream.
    - Page No.: 1
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x80410515 - E - The form xobject Xi34 has an empty or unreadable content stream.
    - Page No.: 1
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x80410515 - E - The form xobject Xi35 has an empty or unreadable content stream.
    - Page No.: 1
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x80410515 - E - The form xobject Xi36 has an empty or unreadable content stream.
    - Page No.: 1
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x80410515 - E - The form xobject Xi37 has an empty or unreadable content stream.
    - Page No.: 1
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x80410515 - E - The form xobject Xi38 has an empty or unreadable content stream.
    - Page No.: 1
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x80410515 - E - The form xobject Xi39 has an empty or unreadable content stream.
    - Page No.: 1
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x80410515 - E - The form xobject Xi40 has an empty or unreadable content stream.
    - Page No.: 1
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x80410515 - E - The form xobject Xi41 has an empty or unreadable content stream.
    - Page No.: 1
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x80410515 - E - The form xobject Xi42 has an empty or unreadable content stream.
    - Page No.: 1
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x80410515 - E - The form xobject Xi43 has an empty or unreadable content stream.
    - Page No.: 1
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x80410515 - E - The form xobject Xi44 has an empty or unreadable content stream.
    - Page No.: 1
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x80410515 - E - The form xobject Xi45 has an empty or unreadable content stream.
    - Page No.: 1
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x80410515 - E - The form xobject Xi46 has an empty or unreadable content stream.
    - Page No.: 1
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x80410515 - E - The form xobject Xi47 has an empty or unreadable content stream.
    - Page No.: 1
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x80410515 - E - The form xobject Xi48 has an empty or unreadable content stream.
    - Page No.: 1
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x80410515 - E - The form xobject Xi49 has an empty or unreadable content stream.
    - Page No.: 1
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x80410515 - E - The form xobject Xi50 has an empty or unreadable content stream.
    - Page No.: 1
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x80410515 - E - The form xobject Xi51 has an empty or unreadable content stream.
    - Page No.: 1
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x80410515 - E - The form xobject Xi52 has an empty or unreadable content stream.
    - Page No.: 1
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x80410515 - E - The form xobject Xi53 has an empty or unreadable content stream.
    - Page No.: 1
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x80410515 - E - The form xobject Xi54 has an empty or unreadable content stream.
    - Page No.: 1
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x80410515 - E - The form xobject Xi55 has an empty or unreadable content stream.
    - Page No.: 1
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x80410515 - E - The form xobject Xi56 has an empty or unreadable content stream.
    - Page No.: 1
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x80410515 - E - The form xobject Xi57 has an empty or unreadable content stream.
    - Page No.: 1
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x80410515 - E - The form xobject Xi58 has an empty or unreadable content stream.
    - Page No.: 1
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x80410515 - E - The form xobject Xi59 has an empty or unreadable content stream.
    - Page No.: 1
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x80410515 - E - The form xobject Xi60 has an empty or unreadable content stream.
    - Page No.: 1
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x80410515 - E - The form xobject Xi61 has an empty or unreadable content stream.
    - Page No.: 1
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x80410515 - E - The form xobject Xi62 has an empty or unreadable content stream.
    - Page No.: 1
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x80410515 - E - The form xobject Xi63 has an empty or unreadable content stream.
    - Page No.: 1
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x80410515 - E - The form xobject Xi64 has an empty or unreadable content stream.
    - Page No.: 1
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x80410515 - E - The form xobject Xi65 has an empty or unreadable content stream.
    - Page No.: 1
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x80410515 - E - The form xobject Xi66 has an empty or unreadable content stream.
    - Page No.: 1
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x80410515 - E - The form xobject Xi67 has an empty or unreadable content stream.
    - Page No.: 1
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x80410515 - E - The form xobject Xi68 has an empty or unreadable content stream.
    - Page No.: 1
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x80410515 - E - The form xobject Xi69 has an empty or unreadable content stream.
    - Page No.: 1
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x80410515 - E - The form xobject Xi70 has an empty or unreadable content stream.
    - Page No.: 1
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
0x80410515 - E - The form xobject Xi71 has an empty or unreadable content stream.
    - Page No.: 1
    - File: CMS-1500.pdf
... (462 lines skipped)
Close file.
3-Heights(TM) PDF repair tool, evaluation license valid until unbounded
```

Comment: Have you saved the bytes, and have you tried to open them in a text editor. I have seen people who didn't know that servers sometimes send HTML with error messages to the browser. They assume: if we tell the server to send PDF to the browser, the server will send PDF *no matter what*.

Comment: Here I'm getting  byte[] as a result from PDFHelper.GeneratePDF(pdfPath, formFieldMap);,Stroing to var pdfContents ,I tried to open in Adobe Reader.Could you be send me some link for reference.I'm novice person to this concept

Comment: Your comment is not an answer to my question. I will repeat my question only once. If you don't understand my question, I cannot help you. At some point you download something from a server (that's what `response.BinaryWrite(contents);` is about). **I asked you to open that result in a text editor.** Your comment "I'm getting byte[]" is irrelevant to me. Your comment "I tried to open in Adobe Reader" **does not answer my question.** If you are a novice, please understand that Stack Overflow **is not a school**. Get a book or get an education.

Comment: ok fine..I have done storing byte[] in. txt file.can able that in notepad.What i have to do next?

Comment: What do you see when you open the byte array in Notepad?

Comment: What you see should start with `%PDF` and end with `%%EOF`. The first error mentioned in your question tells me that `%%EOF` is not there: *The end-of-file marker was not found.*

Comment: Yep,It starts with %PDF  and ends with %%EOF,Same code working in  "AspNetMvc-Version=1.0",If I try same with "AspNetMvc-Version=5.2".I'm getting this error.

Comment: I don't know anything about ASP.NET, so you will have to ask an ASP.NET expert. What makes you think that this problem is related to iText? It seems to me that the PDF can be created correctly, but that the environment makes the bytes corrupt.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149778/discussion-between-kavie-and-bruno-lowagie).